# write a test for WebSocketHandlerDecorator - Delegate must not be null

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, testing, websocket

I want to write a test to test my WebSocketHandlerDecorator, but I encouter some problems.

here is the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Delegate must not be null
>
> at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193)     at
>   org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:42)

```
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.web.socket.CloseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;  

public class MyWebSocketHandlerDecorator extends WebSocketHandlerDecorator {

    public MySocketHandlerDecorator(WebSocketHandler delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final WebSocketSession session, final WebSocketMessage<?> message) throws Exception {

        final TextMessage MyMessage = (TextMessage) message;
        super.handleMessage(session, MyMessage);
    }
}
```

here is my test case:

```
public class MyWebSocketHandlerDecpratorTest {

    @Mock
    private WebSocketSession session;

    @Mock
    WebSocketHandler delegate;

    @Spy
    private WebSocketHandlerDecorator webSocketHandlerDecorator = new WebSocketHandlerDecorator(delegate);

    @InjectMocks
    MyWebSocketHandlerDecorator myWebSocketHandlerDecorator;

    private TextMessage message;

    @Before
    public void set_up(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        message = new TextMessage("Test Message".getBytes());
    }

    @Test
    public void handleMessage()throws Exception{
        myWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(session, message);
        verify(webSocketHandlerDecorator, times(1)).handleMessage(session, message);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me correct my test and figure out what issue it has?

```
public WebSocketHandlerDecorator(WebSocketHandler delegate) {
    Assert.notNull(delegate, "Delegate must not be null");
    this.delegate = delegate;
}
```

Comment: it seems like you have to provide an instance for delegate

Comment: you are right, but WebSocketHandler here is a interface, if I use @mock to mock it as a instance, it is definitly a null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup your `@Spy` in the `@Before` method, because at the time the class is created, the mocks are not yet initialized:

```
public class MyWebSocketHandlerDecpratorTest {
    @Mock
    private WebSocketSession session;

    @Mock
    WebSocketHandler delegate;

    private WebSocketHandlerDecorator webSocketHandlerDecorator;

    @InjectMocks
    MyWebSocketHandlerDecorator myWebSocketHandlerDecorator;

    private TextMessage message;

    @Before
    public void set_up(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        webSocketHandlerDecorator = Mockito.spy(new WebSocketHandlerDecorator(delegate));
        message = new TextMessage("Test Message".getBytes());
    }

    @Test
    public void handleMessage()throws Exception{
        myWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(session, message);
        verify(webSocketHandlerDecorator, times(1)).handleMessage(session, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lino, it can work, but an error occurs :  Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
webSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(
    session,
    TextMessage payload=[Test Messa..], byteCount=13, last=true]
);

Comment: @HungryBird Is the `delegate` or the `webSocketHandlerDecorator` injected into `myWebSocketHandlerDecorator`? If it is the latter then you have to inject the mocks manually (also in the `@Before` method)

Comment: Hi @Lino, when I marked the test file with "@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)", the error(Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock. Wanted but not invoked) occurs again...if I don't provide "@RunWith", it works well,  what is the difference between Runwith default runner and mockito runner? what may result in this case?

Comment: @HungryBird did you remove the `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` from your `@Before` method? Both do the same, but you should only use one. I prefer `@RunWith` as it doesn't clutter my setup code

Comment: Thanks for your solution